# Consulta sql a dos bases de datos con variables php me da error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, sql

Estoy realizando esta consulta `sql` desde `phpmyadmin` y me trae los datos correctamente.

```html
SELECT 4am_traficon.ordinthh.codordint, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fechahh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.codagencia, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.obshh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.horash, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.valhorah, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.valminh, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.nomper, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fecusr, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codagencia
FROM 4am_comsysn.ageperso
INNER JOIN 4am_traficon.ordinthh ON 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper = 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh
WHERE 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codagencia = "4AM" AND 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh = "98520563" AND 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fechahh BETWEEN "2018-12-01" AND "2019-04-25"
ORDER BY fechahh DESC;
```

Cuando paso esta consulta a `php` me da error en consola me dice

> interal server error

**Mi código `php`:**

En mi conexión no estoy indicando la base de datos **¿Puede ser un problema ya que le indico que base de datos usar en la consulta?**

```html
 if(isset($_POST["codagencia"], $_POST["codper"], $_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
      $connecttwo = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Tr4ff1cfouraM!by?S4atchi");
      $connecttwo->set_charset("utf8");
      $output = '';  
      $sql  = 'SELECT 4am_traficon.ordinthh.codordint, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fechahh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.codagencia, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.obshh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.horash, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.valhorah, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.valminh, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.nomper, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fecusr, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codagencia\n"

    . "FROM 4am_comsysn.ageperso\n"

    . "INNER JOIN 4am_traficon.ordinthh ON 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper = 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh\n"

    . "WHERE 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codagencia = '".$_POST["codagencia"]."' AND 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh = '".$_POST["codper"]."' AND 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fechahh BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'\n"

    . "ORDER BY fechahh DESC';
```

En mi código `ajax` estoy enviado correctamente los datos

Código `Ajax`:

```html
      $('#filter').click(function(){  
        from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        codagencia = $('#brand').val();
        codper = $('#show_product').val();
        //console.log(codcli, from_date, to_date);
        if(codagencia != "" && codper != "" && from_date != '' && to_date != '')  {  
             $.ajax({  
                  url:"user_data.php",  
                  method:"POST",  
                  data:{codagencia:codagencia, codper:codper, from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
                  beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#order_table').css('background', 'url(/img/ajaxloader.gif) no-repeat center top')
                  },
                  complete: function(){
                    $('#order_table').css('background', 'none')
                  },
                  success:function(data)  
                  {  
                       $('#order_table').html(data);  
                  }  
             });  
        } else{  
             alert("Selecione agencia, usuario y rango de fechas");  
        }  
     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error 500 ocurre cuando el código de servidor (PHP) tiene errores.

En este caso tu código tiene errores de sintaxis. No cierras el `if`, y la forma de concatenar la consulta SQL es dudosa, usando `\n` en vez de simples espacios en blanco... tampoco hace falta usar tantos puntos para unir líneas, puedes escribirlo en una sola variable.

Inténtalo así, en este código he guardado los datos del POST en variables mediante un ternario, luego usarlos es mucho más claro y más fácil.

```
$codAgencia=!empty ($_POST["codagencia"]) ? $_POST["codagencia"] : NULL;
$codPer    =!empty ($_POST["codper"])     ? $_POST["codper"]     : NULL;
$fromDate  =!empty ($_POST["from_date"])  ? $_POST["from_date"]  : NULL;
$toDate    =!empty ($_POST["to_date"])    ? $_POST["to_date"]    : NULL;
$output = '';  

 if($codAgencia && $codPer && $fromDate && $toDate)  
 {  
      $connecttwo = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Tr4ff1cfouraM!by?S4atchi");
      $connecttwo->set_charset("utf8");
      $sql  = "SELECT 4am_traficon.ordinthh.codordint, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fechahh, 
          4am_traficon.ordinthh.codagencia, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.obshh, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.horash, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.valhorah,
          4am_traficon.ordinthh.valminh, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.nomper, 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fecusr, 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codagencia 
      FROM 4am_comsysn.ageperso 
          INNER JOIN 4am_traficon.ordinthh ON 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codper = 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh 
      WHERE 4am_comsysn.ageperso.codagencia = '$codAgencia' 
          AND 4am_traficon.ordinthh.responhh = '$codPer' 
          AND 4am_traficon.ordinthh.fechahh BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'
      ORDER BY fechahh DESC";
      /*Aquí supongo que se hará algo con el resultado y se asignará a $output*/
      $output="¿Haras algo con los datos?";
}
else
{
    $output="Faltan datos en el POST";      
}
echo $output;
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta me ha ayudado!
Soy algo novato en php y trato de aprender lo más rápido posible.